# Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value : flutter_native_timezone

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the below error while initializing the time zone in main method using `flutter_native_timezone`.

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
        MethodChannel.binaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:121:86)    
        MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:146:36)    
        MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
        FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone 
       (package:flutter_native_timezone/flutter_native_timezone.dart:17:24)
        configureLocalTimeZone (package:myapp/main.dart:48:60)
        main (package:myapp/main.dart:16:9)
        runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:145:25)
        rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1428:13)`enter code here`
        CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
        runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1863:10)
```

Using the below plugins:

```
package:timezone/data/latest_10y.dart as tz
package:timezone/timezone.dart as tz
```

Code Snippet:

```
Future<void> configureLocalTimeZone() async {
         if (kIsWeb || Platform.isLinux) {
          return;
         }
          tz.initializeTimeZones();
          final String? timeZoneName = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
          tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName!));
          }
```

Comment: `// @dart=2.9`      Paste this code in the main.dart file in the first line above the import file

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess you do not read your own code, or have simply not understood what dart null safety *is*. I strongly urge you to read *and understand* [Dart nullsafety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety), this feature is here to stay and you will not be able to properly write code if you don't understand it. Dart null safety is *not* about randomly slapping `?` and `!` on stuff until it compiles.

This line *explicitely says* that the variable `timeZoneName` *can be null*:

```
final String? timeZoneName = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
```

...and then in the very next line, you tell the compiler, *pinky promise, I **swear** this variable will **never** be null.*

```
      tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName!));
```

Well, guess what happened? It *was* null. You lied to your compiler and the compiler caught you.

What can you do? Instead of lying to your compiler to make it compile, you could *understand* what you have to do to write a proper program. In this case, you need to insert an `if` and only invoke your second line, if you have a `timeZoneName`. What to do if you don't? I don't know, that is your job to decide. Maybe log an error message? But don't tell your compiler it is wrong. That will only lead to errors like the one you got.